# How to send a DatagramPacket to multiple ip addresses?

Tags: java, networking, datagram

I'm trying to make a simple network multiplayer game in java. In the server program I take DatagramPackets from every clients including their details (in a String). Then I add them into a HashMap and I want that HashMap to be sent to all players.

```
server.receive(packet);
String data=new String(packet.getData(),0,packet.getLength());
String[] usrData=data.split("=");
clients.put(usrData[0], usrData[1]);
makePacket();
//here I want to send HashMap to send to all clients.
```

Question is how can i send a packet to multiple computers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a MulticastSocket on the recipient(client) side, take a look at this tutorial from Oracle [Broadcasting to Multiple Recipients](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/broadcasting.html)

Comment: I read this article and many other related to MalticastSocket. How can I find a ip address for the group? Any of those articles do not tell about that.

Comment: [See this](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_IPMulticastAddressing-2.htm) One thing that we need to take into consideration here, is that there are specific addresses that allow us to use a MulticastSocket are limited, specifically in the range of 224.0.0.0 to 239.255.255.255. Some of them are reserved, like 224.0.0.0. The address that we are using, 224.0.0.3, can be used safely.
[See also](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/net/multicastsocket-net/java-net-multicastsocket-example/)